# In the TXQ G63 (aka MyDEL G63), what are Compander, Scramble, Frequency hop, SPEC, SPEC Code and Scan Add?

Tags: ht

This is the software use to *program* the TXQ G63:

[image]

I think I have a guess about Compander and Scramble, but I'm totally lost when it comes to Frequency hop, SPEC, SPEC Code and Scand Add.

Do you know what they are?